# Beacon: dBm power decrease over distance

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, decibel

I have beacons which advertise their configured data periodically through Bluetooth. The vendor specifies 8 different power options 0 to 7: https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201621521-Transmission-power-Range-and-RSSI

With a configured power option 7 (which is equal to 4 dBm) I should receive (RSSI) a value of -59 dBm in a distance of 1 meter.

Is there a formula to allow me calculating the expected RSSI value in 3 meters distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have clear line of site (no obstructions), you will get 1/4 the power (6 dB less) every time you double the distance.

So in this case you would get -59 dBm - 6 dB * log2(range / 1 meter) or -59 dBm - 19 dB = -68.5 dBm

For much more info on this, check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation

Comment: I love you, thank you very much. I wish I could but I'm not that well trained to work this out on myself, so maybe you know the answer to this one too: How would the formula look like if I knew the received dBm and the calibrated value @ 1m and I'd like to know the distance? So input is -78 dBm & -59 dBm, expected output is 3 m. Something with log2() too, right? :-)

Comment: No problem!  estimated distance is 2 ^ ( ( -59 dBm - power received ) / 6 ).  But be careful, the power at 1 meter might not be as accurately provided as one would hope ;)

Comment: hum, am I calculating it wrong?
-59 dBm - -78 dBm = 19 dBm | 
19 dBm / 6 = 3.16 dBm | 
2^3.16 dBm = 8.98 (m) ? Maybe with sqrt() it would be right, but that's just a guess :-)

Comment: Opps, my original arithmetic was wrong.  Should have been -68.5 dBm, that should give you 3 meters.  sorry about that!!!!

Comment: No worries, thank you very much. I really appreciate your help. Would you mind answering one last question regarding your equation? why is [dBm] minus [dB] equal to something in [dBm]? Assuming that I enter "3m" / "1m" in the log2 term. or should I just enter "3m/1" so the "m" stays?

Comment: How would I calculate a distance of a BLE device if the power of transmitting(tx power) is -7dBm and at 1m RSSI is 70dBm?